# What has to be done to switch database file in connection in sqlite/delphi

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

I hope this is not some embarrassing user error, but here goes:

I want to change the database parameter for the connection and reopen it.  This code continues to display (and allow for editing of) the original table connection rather than refreshing.  Is there some kind of 'flush' or refresh I must call?

```
dmMain.conMain.close;
dmMain.conMain.Params.Values['Database'] := secondDatabase;
dmMain.conMain.Open;
dmMain.tblTimings.Active := true;
```

I subsequently tried conMain.Connected := false to no effect.

Comment: Was `tblTimings`, or some other related object, still active?

Comment: Yes, and I was expecting it to self-close upon the connection closing, but I'll give that a try.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not happen (all linked datasets should be closed), so I would call it a bug (you're doing it right in your code). See the [**Close**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TCustomConnection.Close) method description:

> **TCustomConnection.Close**
>
> Closes the connection.
>
> Call Close to disconnect from the remote source of database
>   information. Before the connection component is deactivated, all
>   associated datasets are closed. Calling Close is the same as setting
>   the Connected property to false.
>
> In most cases, closing a connection frees system resources allocated
>   to the connection.
>
> Note: If a previously active connection is closed and then reopened,
>   any associated datasets must be individually reopened; reopening the
>   connection does not automatically reopen associated datasets.

Answer (score -3):

Per the Delphi documentation, you need to `ATTACH` the second database to the existing connection.

```
dmMain.ConMain.ExecSQL('ATTACH '+QuotedStr(secondDatabase)+ ' as SecondDB');
```

To remove a database, use `DETACH`

Full documentation is here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC

Comment: Thank you.  I read that documentation to be about accessing multiple simultaneous databases, whereas I am trying to replace the main database, but I'll give it a try!